# Task - email is not deleting after acceptance

Tags: microsoft-outlook, tasks

My Outlook is not deleting the email after accepting the task and if I try manually delete the task is declined.

My Outlook options:
[image: Outlook option "delete meeting requests and notifications from Inbox after responding" is enabled]

Comment: What version of Outlook? What type of e-mail account do you have (Exchange/Office 365, POP, IMAP)? Have you always had this problem or did it start recently, and if the latter, any thoughts on what might have changed?

Answer (score 0):

Task emails cannot be automatically deleted after accepting/declining. The option highlighted in red box in your screenshot only applies to meeting requests and notifications. Moreover, once you delete the task message in your Inbox, it actually deletes the task entry in your Tasks folder.